# How can I calculate the nonlinear system gains?

Tags: matlab

Are there any codes in matlab to to calculate the gains of state-space matrix for nonlinear system? the system equations are written in differential equations and I used Runge-Kutta 4th Order Method to get the dynamic response of the states with time.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. If you are talking about gains, then there is an assumption that you have some controller or observer also. Please tell us more about your system and what you are trying to do. Also this may be better suited for [Math](http://math.stackexchange.com), [Robotics](http://robotics.stackexchange.com) or [EE](http://electronics.stackexchange.com) stack exchanges, as your question is not about programming, so much as using MATLAB to do some calculation.